# how to enable symlink in laravel 6.x error

Tags: php, laravel

**This error occur when i upload my website on server in localhost it was working fine** 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iVVuN.png)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of use **storage:link**, now you can use like this!

```
ln -s /home/your_application/storage/app/public /home/your_application/public/storage
```

But, you know what, you can’t access your file with instead what you can do is, define the name of your symbolic, so become `asset("storage/{$path"}).`

One thing, just to make sure your link seems good, I prefer to change the name of folder.

```
ln -s /home/your_application/storage/app/public /home/your_application/public/images
```

**Referrer :** https://medium.com/@irsyadadl/symlink-has-been-disabled-for-any-fuckin-security-reasons-3b2f42f879b7

Comment: That is right but I dont have ssh access, I am using shared hosting.